# Local Link Multicast Name Resolution replaces NetBIOS, yet textbook says otherwise

Tags: windows-server-2008, netbios, unc

I am studying from Configuring Windows Server 2008 Network Infrastructure (our environment still has significant Windows 2008 R2 servers), and one question asks

> You are working on a Windows Server 2008 R2 computer named WS08A. You
>   cannot connect to computers running Windows XP on the local network by
>   specifying them by name in a UNC path such as \computer1.
>
> What can you do to enable your computer to connect to these computers
>   by specifying them in a UNC?

The choices are

> Enable IPv6 on WS08A.
>
> Enable NetBIOS on WS08A.
>
> Enable Local Link Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR) on WS08A.
>
> Disable IPv6 on WS08A.

I believe the correct choice is `Enable Local Link Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR) on WS08A.` because it replaces NetBIOS. However, the textbook says `Enable NetBIOS on WS08A` is the answer.

When I researched this, I read somewhere that using LLMRN to connect to a 32bit machine will take longer than if you use NetBIOS, but this connection is still possible.

http://www.schoolleader.com/Documentation/Disabling_LLMNR_Causing_Slow_Networks.pdf

If this is the case, why can't they re-write the question to ask,

> "Which is the faster way to connect to Windows XP by specifying them
>   in a UNC?"

Or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use LLMNR in that scenario because [it was introduced with Windows Vista/Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878128.aspx). [Windows XP does not support it](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/04/01/how-to-benefit-from-link-local-multicast-name-resolution.aspx).

Since Windows XP is end of life, and nobody should be using it anymore, (though some are) you can use LLMNR once you have completely eliminated XP from your environment.